# Selecting specific non-empty nodes with Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have two Xpath requests:

```
$was_price_location = "//ul[@id='items']/li/div[@class='productprice']/span[@class='price' or @class='recRP rrp']";
$now_price_location = "//ul[@id='items']/li/div[@class='productprice']/span[@class='prevPrice previousprice' or @class='price outlet-current-price']";
```

However, I want to modify it so that only those nodes specified that are **not** empty are returned.

At the moment, it's finding excess `<span class="recRP rrp">` and `<span class="prevPrice previousprice">` nodes that are empty and therefore irrelevant to me.

Comment: Add `and text() != ''` or `and normalize-space(text()) != ''`

Comment: @JWiley Neither of would not work reliably if the `span` elements have any child elements (such as `<b>` or `<em>`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$prod_price_location = "//ul[@id='items']/li/div[@class='productprice']";
$was_price_location = $prod_price_location . 
    "/span[@class='price' or @class='recRP rrp'][normalize-space()]";
$now_price_location = $prod_price_location . 
    "/span[@class='prevPrice previousprice' or @class='price outlet-current-price']" .
    "[normalize-space()]";
```